# Calculating distance between co-ordinates in maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
import React from "react";
import PlacesAutocomplete, {
geocodeByAddress,
getLatLng
 } from "react-places-autocomplete";
import {db} from './Firebase';
import {useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Places() {
const [address, setAddress] = React.useState("");
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = React.useState({
  lat: null,
  lng: null,
travelMode: "DRIVING"
});

const [destination, setDestinations] = React.useState([]);


let origins = [(coordinates.lat), (coordinates.lng)]
let travelMode = (coordinates.travelMode)

 let destinations = destination.map(
position => {
  return  [(position.Latitude), (position.Longitude)]
}
)



useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db.collection('Location').onSnapshot (snapshot => {
       const allPositions = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ... doc.data()
      }));
      setDestinations(allPositions);
   })
 return () => {
    unsub();
};
}, [])

const handleSelect = async value => {
const results = await geocodeByAddress(value);
const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
setAddress(value);
setCoordinates(latLng);

};

console.log (destinations)

return (
  <div>
    <PlacesAutocomplete
      value={address}
      onChange={setAddress}
      onSelect={handleSelect}
   >
    {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
      <div>
        <p>Latitude: {coordinates.lat}</p>
        <p>Longitude: {coordinates.lng}</p>

        <input {...getInputProps({ placeholder: "Type address" })} />

        <div>
          {loading ? <div>...loading</div> : null}

          {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
            const style = {
              backgroundColor: suggestion.active ? "#41b6e6" : "#fff"
            };

            return (
              <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { style })}>
                {suggestion.description}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </PlacesAutocomplete>
</div>
);
}
```

I'm trying to calculate the distance between a set of co-ordinates, a pair of co-ordinates are gotten from the co-ordinates state, while the other sets of co-ordinates is gotten from the destination state after being fetched from a database. I've tried using react libraries for the Google Distance Matrix but I'm getting a CORS block error in the console.

Comment: can your provide the actual CORS error you are getting? Probably worth updating the question title to reflect your actual issue.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?index=&origins=-7.841879%2C110.409193&destinations=-7.741194%2C110.342588&mode=driving&units=metric&language=en&avoid=&sensor=false&key= from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. That's the error message, I've removed the api key in the url

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483478/google-maps-api-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing-error

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use Distance Matrix service for client side application of Distance Matrix. Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/distance-matrix-nle4qx?file=src/components/distancematrix.js) I made to implement it. Make sure to change the API key in this line:

```
const API_KEY = "CHANGE_API_KEY_HERE";
```

Here is how the distancematrix.js file looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const map;
var markers=[];
var infowindow;
const API_KEY = "CHANGE_API_KEY_HERE" ;

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      origin: '',
      dest: '',
      distance: '',
      duration: ''
    }; 

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); 
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this);

  }

  onScriptLoad() {
    map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.props.id), this.props.options);
    this.props.onMapLoad(map)

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`+API_KEY+`&libraries=places,geometry`;
      script.id = 'googleMaps';
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener('load', e => {
        this.onScriptLoad()
      })
    }
    else {
      this.onScriptLoad()
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 },
      map: map
    });
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  handleBlur = (field) => (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      touched: { ...this.state.touched, [field]: true },
    });
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.getDistanceMatrix();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  geocodeAddress(addressResult) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    console.log(addressResult[0]);
    var address1 = addressResult[0];
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address1 }, (results, status)=> {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        this.createMarker(results[0]); 
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }


getDistanceMatrix(){


var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    var orig = this.state.origin;
    var dest = this.state.dest;
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [orig],
          destinations: [dest],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, (response, status) => {
          if (status !== 'OK') { 
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
          } else {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            this.geocodeAddress(origins);
            this.geocodeAddress(destinations);

            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              console.log(response);
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
              var element = results[j];
              console.log(element);
              var distanceString = element.distance.text;
              var durationString = element.duration.text;
              //add new value to the previousValue 
              this.setState ({
                distance:  distanceString
                });

              this.setState ({
                duration: durationString
                });

               }

               console.log(this.state.distance + ','+ this.state.duration)
             }
          }
          });

}


  createMarker(place) {
    var image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      title: place.formatted_address,
      icon: image
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var content =
      'Formatted Address: ' + place.formatted_address +
      '<br/>Location Type: ' + place.geometry.location_type +
      '<br/>Address Type: ' + place.types +
      '<br/>Place ID: ' + place.place_id; 

    marker.addListener('click', ()=>{     
      infowindow.setContent(content);  
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div id="root">
      <div className="map" id={this.props.id} />
      <h1 htmlFor="input">Get Distance Matrix</h1>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin"
                    placeholder="origin"
                    value={this.state.origin}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    &nbsp;
       <input type="text" id="dest" name="dest"
                    placeholder="destination"
                    value={this.state.dest}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    <br/><br/>
        <button type="submit" color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                    Submit
                  </button><br/><br/>
                  <h1 htmlFor="input">Results </h1> &nbsp;
                  <label htmlFor="input"> Distance:{this.state.distance}</label><br/>
                  <label htmlFor="input"> Duration:{this.state.duration}</label>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Map;
```